# What to do with the [ph] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Usage guidance for [acid-base](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acid-base) ([2091 questions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acid-base))

> This tag should be applied to questions concerning acid and base reactions.

Usage guidance for [ph](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ph) ([558 questions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ph))

> pH (or the potential of hydrogen) is a scale used to measure how acidic or basic an aqueous solution is.

Questions with both: [312](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acid-base+ph)

There are a number of questions that ask about pH values specifically. The two options that I think good arguments could be made for are:

1. Make [ph](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ph) a synonym of [acid-base](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acid-base)
2. Edit the guidance for [ph](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ph) such that is is sufficiently distinct from [acid-base](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acid-base)

Thoughts?

Comment: Leave it as it is? What's the issue.

Comment: @AvnishKabaj Mostly its unclear when to use pH or not.

Comment: Note there is also an [tag:acid] tag which so far has never been applied... wait I see, I guess that's an alias for acid-base.